# What is a SCPI command for OWON XDS3202A so to grab a display image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oscilloscope

I need to capture the display image of a OWON XDS3202A oscilloscope, a digital copy, and do it via Python, however, I don't know the appropriate SCPI command to grab the screen dump (like SCDP command in Siglent SDS oscilloscopes). I've looked up in the user manual yet found nothing. So, what is the appropriate command?